# How to execute javascript only when jquery overlay is invoked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, scrollbar, overlay

I have a simple jquery overlay set up on an aspx page.  Here is the relevant code:

```
<img rel="#1208" src="/images/testsmall.png" />
<div class="simple_overlay" id="1208"><img src="/images/testlarge.png" /></div>
```

Using jquery library:

```
http://cdn.jquerytools.org/1.2.7/full/jquery.tools.min.js
```

and script:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $("img[rel]").overlay();
    });
</script>
```

On the page itself there is a javascript scrollbar for a section that this code sits inside of:

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#scrollbar2').tinyscrollbar();
        });
    </script>
</head>
```

The thing is, I'd like to disable the scrollbar ONLY when the overlay is invoked.  Fairly new to jquery and javascript, and though I know how to hide the scrollbar with javascript's hide() method, I'm not sure how to code it to only be invoked when the overlay is invoked.  That, or if there's a better way to do this than the hide() method.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if there's a better method than calling `.hide()` on the scrollbar, but you can use the `onLoad` and `onClose` events of the overlay to control when it should happen:

```
$("img[rel]").overlay({
    onLoad: function(event) {
        // hide the scrollbar
    },
    onClose: function(event) {
        // show the scrollbar
    }
});
```

More information about the options, events and methods of the overlay can be found in the [jQuery tools Overlay documentation](http://jquerytools.org/documentation/overlay/index.html#events). More general information about events with jQuery tools can be found [here](http://jquerytools.org/documentation/scripting.html#events).

Comment: This did the trick!  I used onBeforeLoad instead of onLoad and added a speed to the hide--.hide("fast")--so that my overlay's fadein didn't occur first and before an abrupt disappearance of my scrollbar.

Answer (score 1):

You could hide/disable the scroll bar onLoad() of the overlay. Then onClose() of the overlay you could show the show/enable the scroll bar.

Check out the documentation for onLoad() and onClose() for your overlay.

http://jquerytools.org/documentation/overlay/

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
$.getScript("ajax/test.js", function(data, textStatus, jqxhr) {
console.log(data); //data returned
console.log(textStatus); //success
console.log(jqxhr.status); //200
console.log('Load was performed.');
});
```

Should do the trick. Take a look also on  this: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/

Answer (score 0):

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
            var callBack = function(){
                $('#scrollbar2').tinyscrollbar();
            };
            $("img[rel]").overlay(callBack);
            // then call this callback function inside overlay function
        });
```